# Encrypting a generic type in java

Tags: java, encryption

I have some problem working on generic type in java 8. 
In a project i'm working on, i have those 3 class

```
public class User{
    private String Id;
    private String password;
}

public class Data<E>{
    private <E> data;
    private String Owner; //can read and write the data
    private Vector<String> Others; //can only read the data
}

public class MySecureDataContainer<E>{
    Vector<User> users;
    Vector<Data<E>> data;

    public share(String Id, String passw, E data, String Other);
}
```

i just wrote here the elements where i have problems.
The idea is simple: the MySecureDataContainer class works in local, without threads or socket. each user of the vector, once registered, can create a data, modify it, read all the data he created, share a data with another user. each operation works only if the user "log in".

One of the tasks of the project is to encrypt all the generics data each user create. so i have 2 problems:
1) how can i encrypt a generic type? (the idea is to use the password as a key)
2) if the data is encrypted, how can i share it with another user? and, plus it, how can another user read the data, if he can only read it, without knowing the password of the owner? 
I can add variabiles in the classes, but i can not add variabiles into the method

Comment: You can't read encrypted data without required decryption tools. That's like the whole purpose of using encryption.......

Comment: can i use an asimmetric encryption such as RSA? if i need to share if with someone else i decipher it with my private key and crypt again with the key of the other user

Comment: The compiler uses generic types to ensure certain properties of the program at compile time. You don't "encrypt generic types". You encrypt `byte[]` arrays. Types and byte arrays live in two completely different realms. To achieve what you described there, you would need some kind of serialization, encryption, communication over network, decryption, deserialization, and then you would also have to decide how to identify the users, how to share the keys and so on and so forth... That's way too broad. Please limit your question to one specific problem, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Few other hints: 1) The convention for members and variables in Java is usually `camelCaseStartingWithLowerCaseLetter`. 2) The `private <E> data;` doesn't seem quite right, you probably meant something like `private E data`?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) how can i encrypt a generic type? (the idea is to use the password as a key)

As already commented, encryption works on top of byte arrays. You may still have a way how to transform your data into a byte array and back, e.g. by Java serialization, XML, JSON, EDI, .. whatever. This is out of scope of this answer.  Once you have a way to serialize and de-serialize, you can encrypt or decrypt the serialized (byte array) form

Using user's credential password to encrypt data itself may not be the best idea. The user may not want to pass its password. You may use a random encryption key and then some sort of asymmetric encryption to pass the encrypted key.

> 2) if the data is encrypted, how can i share it with another user? and, plus it, how can another user read the data, if he can only read it, without knowing the password of the owner?

Indeed RSA (or other asymmetric encryption) allow sending data to different user without exchanging the user's private key or password itself.

> I can add variables in the classes, but i can not add variables into the method

you can use method variables, but they are variables in the method scope, not object attributes